# Galaxy S4: onHover/Airview for Input Method not working

Tags: android, galaxy, android-input-method, onhover

## AirView in InputMethod not working

I am trying to use the new AirView feature of the Samsung Galaxy S4, specifically the onHover-event. I already have it working a normal application by...

- targeting API level 17
- providing an onHover event listener
- setting the intent filter for com.sec.android.airview.HOVER

Now I want to use it for an input method. My problem is that the view of the input method does not get any onHover events, even though I also set the airview intent filter:

Excerpt of AndroidManifest.xml:

```xml
<application android:label="@string/ime_name"
    <service android:name="com.example.keyboard"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.view.InputMethod" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.sec.android.airview.HOVER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.view.im" android:resource="@xml/method" />
    </service>
</application>
```

For the moment I have a simple LinearLayout with a single button in my input method layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hover Button"
        android:id="@+id/hoverbutton2"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The event listener is set like this:

```java
Button hoverButton = (Button) mInputView.findViewById(R.id.hoverbutton2);
hoverButton.setOnHoverListener(new View.OnHoverListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onHover(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d(TAG, "hoverButton2: onHover");
        return false;
    }
});
```

An onClick listener set in the same fashion works as intended.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  I found the solution posted by furbyx92 on xda dev:

1. First thing is to make sure on the DEVICE in the Settings that AirView is set to ON with all its subsettings ON as well.
2. Next the android manifest:

   ```
   <application
       android:allowBackup="true"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
       <meta-data
           android:name="com.sec.android.airview.enable"
           android:value="true" />
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="com.sec.android.airview.HOVER" />
       </intent-filter>
       <activity
           android:name="edu.uanl.secondapp.MainActivity"
           android:label="@string/app_name" >
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="com.sec.android.airview.HOVER" />
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>
   </application>
   ```
3. In your code:

   ```
   textView.setOnHoverListener(new View.OnHoverListener() {
       @override
       public boolean onHover(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
           switch(motionEvent.getAction()){
               case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_ENTER : // Enter Hovered
               case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_EXIT:   // Leave Hovered
                   view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                   view.setScaleX((float)1.0);
                   view.setScaleY((float)1.0);
                   break;
               case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_MOVE:   // On Hover
                   view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                   view.setScaleX((float)2.0);
                   view.setScaleY((float)2.0);
                   break;
           }
           Log.wtf("Something", "I'm Being Hovered" + motionEvent.getAction());
           return false;
       }
   });
   textView.setHovered(true);
   ```

Comment: That is exactly what I would do for an **app**, but I am trying to get the hover events from inside an **Input Method**. That aside, you are setting the intent filter twice in your AndroidManifest.xml. I believe the one in application is unnecessary.